# macports use python install

Tags: python, macports

Sorry, I'm sure this is a stupid question.

I have successfully installed python 2.6 with macports. How do I use that version of python? The version that shows when I type python in term is python 2.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the port select command to choose it

1. List the available pythons to select from:

   ```
   port select --list python
   ```
2. to choose a specific port (eg python26):

   ```
   port select python python26
   ```

However python2.6 will also choose the version specific one

Comment: great thanks! That did it for me. I swear I tried python2.6... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Call it from the terminal:

python26 PYTHONFILE.py

Answer (score -1):

One way to find Python on your Mac is to type in the command line:

> which python

When I type this, I get:

> /usr/bin/python

You can see other pythons there by typing

> ls /usr/bin/python*

For example, I see:

> /usr/bin/python
>
> /usr/bin/python2.7
>
> /usr/bin/python-config
>
> /usr/bin/python2.7-config
>
> /usr/bin/python2.5
>
> /usr/bin/pythonw
>
> /usr/bin/python2.5-config
>
> /usr/bin/pythonw2.5
>
> /usr/bin/python2.6
>
> /usr/bin/pythonw2.6
>
> /usr/bin/python2.6-config
>
> /usr/bin/pythonw2.7

Then, you can run v2.6 by typing

> /usr/bin/python2.6

Or, since /usr/bin/ is probably in your path, just:

> python2.6

This isn't exactly MacPorts-specific, sorry.

Comment: and won't find the python he wants as that is in /opt/local/bin wilst the apple supplied one is in /usr/bin